# Ajaxify Menu Links

Tags: hooks, routes

I have menu on left column, When we click menu-link I need to post data in right column without page refresh. I am looking to ajaxify menu.

Could you please give me an example how to ajaxify menu links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really simple by using Drupal ajax framework.

First, define your menu callback page.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function yourmodule_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['yourmodule/callback-page'] = array(
    'title' => 'AJAX callback - refresh the elements on the right hand',
    'page callback' => 'yourmodule_refresh',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}
```

Secondly, do ajax deliver on callback page.

```
/**
 * Menu callback.
 */
function yourmodule_refresh($action, $type) {
  if ($type != 'ajax') {
    // This is js only.
    return 'Oh well';
  }

  $content = t('What ever you want');

  $commands = array();
  $commands[] = ajax_command_replace('.right-hand-wrapper-class', $content);
  $page = array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
  ajax_deliver($page);
}
```

Comment: Does this work? How can the page be in the menu if the type is MENU_CALLBACK. Also, there are two arguments in the page callback but only 1 in the menu item arguments array so the example above will fail.

Comment: This is my fault on the explain the way we get the second parameter to use ajax. But the above code work well, Drupal hook menu enough smart to understand the second parameter :). You only need put second on case you use. For example, call "yourmodule/callback-page/ajax" link with class 'use-ajax'.

Comment: My understanding is this would work using a link with 'use-ajax' class. But how would this work inside a menu? Adding 'use-ajax' does not work for menu items?

Comment: Can you update this answer on how to create the link? Adding "use-ajax" does not work.

Comment: I got this working by binding the ajax event to the menu items manually. Google "new Drupal.ajax(base, this, element_settings)"

Comment: @TranHuy This is not working for me. :(